# How to annotate violin bowing over a triplet

Tags: notation, bowing

I am new (6 months) to both violin and music; forgive the simple question. My understanding of general bowing is:

1. Without a slur, bow direction alternates with each note
2. With a slur, maintain the same bow direction

I'm composing a simple melody (common time) and I have a triplet where I want the first two notes down bow, but the last note up bow. A few options I've considered:

1. Slur the first two notes of the triplet only
2. Slur the whole triplet, but mark the final note as up bow
3. No slur, mark down bow for second note

I'm sure there's no "right way" to do this, and as long as the idea is conveyed to the reader then whatever works, but since I'm new to music I'm curious about the general convention. I could not find any examples of what I'm looking for either online or in my beginner books.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a violinist, what would probably be easiest to read and most valid is the first solution you suggested.

The second solution doesn't make sense to my knowledge, and I don't think I've seen any other music do similar bow changes in a slur.

For the third solution, this could also be valid if you don't want the first two notes to flow smoothly into each other, but in this case it'd be much easier to understand if you put a down bow on both the first and second note to indicate you want them in the same direction.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is understandable, since there are multiple ways to indicate both triplets and bow directions! But some are better than others.

Sometimes triplets have been indicated with a "3" and nothing else, like in this second bar:

[image]

The problem with this is that the "3" might be mistaken for a fingering, or in some more complex tuplets it might be harder to see which notes are included. It's more common, especially today, to use square brackets like this:

[image]

Occasionally you see slur marks substituted for these brackets, like this:

[image]

You can see an example at [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/70690/78419), or find people [arguing about the practice on the Musescore forum](https://musescore.org/en/node/39961). As that thread shows, it has been done plenty in the past, and perhaps today when someone's engraving abilities lack square brackets. But the disadvantage of this is obvious, it can be mistaken for an actual slur. Modern practice strongly discourages this.

Meanwhile, when engraving violin music, there's a difference between this:
[image]

... and this:
[image]

A true slur mark means that the bow keeps moving in a downbow direction without any interruption. The two down bows without a slur can be heard as two separate notes that just happen to both be in the same direction, but the player might stop the bow in between them, or even lift it and replace it to start again at the same point, causing an even bigger gap.

(Note, sometimes orchestra players in a hurry might pencil in something like the second example when they mean the first, but if you want a true slur, the best engraving practice is to print one.)